# How to merge values of two lists together

Tags: c#, .net, windows

For example I have:

```
public static List<int> actorList = new List<int>();
public static List<string> ipList = new List<string>();
```

They both have various items in.

So I tried joining the values (string and int) together using a foreach loop:

```
  foreach (string ip in ipList)
    {
        foreach (int actor in actorList)
        {
            string temp = ip + " " + actor;
            finalList.Add(temp);
        }
    }

    foreach (string final in finalList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(finalList);
    }
```

Although looking back at this, this was pretty stupid and obviously will not work, as the first forloop is nested.

My expected values for finalList list:

```
actorListItem1 ipListItem1
actorListItem2 ipListItem2
actorListItem3 ipListItem3
```

and so on..

So the values from the two lists are concatenated with each other - corresponding of their position in the lists order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use `ZIP` function of LINQ**

```
List<string> finalList = actorList.Zip(ipList, (x,y) => x + " " + y).ToList();


finalList.ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x)); // For Displaying
```

**OR combine them in one line**

```
actorList.Zip(ipList,(x,y)=>x+" "+y).ToList().ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Answer (score 3):

What about some functional goodness?

```
listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => a + " " + b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the indexes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ipList.Count; ++i)
{
    string temp = ipList[i] + " " + actorList[i];
    finalList.Add(temp);
}
```

You may also want to add code before this to verify that the lists are the same length:

```
if (ipList.Count != actorList.Count)
{
    // throw some suitable exception
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can use .NET 4, you want to look at the [Zip extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) and the provided example:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };

// The following example concatenates corresponding elements of the
// two input sequences.
var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first + " " + second);
foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
Console.WriteLine();
```

In this example, because there is no corresponding entry for "4" in `words`, it is omitted from the output. You would need to do some checking to make sure the collections are the same length before you start.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<actorList.Count; i++)
{
   finalList.Add(actorList[i] + " " + ipList[i]);
}
```